# Как проверить является ли строчка цифро-буквенной?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Можно пройтись в цикле по всем символам строки, проверяя каждую, является ли она буквой или цифрой, но это решение не выглядит изящным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для подобных задач подходят регулярные выражения.

```
function isAlphaNumeric(input) {
    var regexp = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;        
    return regexp.test(input);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте это выражение:

```
^[\w\d]+$
```